# Error comes while installation of random module of python

Tags: python, pip, requirements

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-random (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-random
```

Comment: `random` module comes preinstalled with python?

Comment: Go search [pypi](https://pypi.org/) for the exact command you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module, since it's a [`built-in`](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html) module and it comes with the standard Python installation.

---

If you want to use its functions and classes, you just have to [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) it:

```
# main.py
import random
print(random.randint(0, 100)) # 42
```